# Gitlab CI - Composer not found with ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci

When connecting with ssh to my webserver I try to install composer dependencies after git pull. But the pipeline fails saying `bash: composer: command not found`. But there is definitely composer installed on the server.

I can also mount my docker image and try it directly with no problem!
Does anyone has an Idea why composer is not found?

Here the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: parallactic/php-node:php8.0-node14.x
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  script:
    - ssh ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_SERVER} "cd ${DEPLOY_DIR} && git pull origin main"
    - ssh ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_SERVER} "cd ${DEPLOY_DIR} && composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader"

  only:
    - main
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may be that your *DEPLOY_USER* doesn't have composer in the *PATH*. you can check that with `echo $PATH` in this deploy script, and then manually connect with your user and compare the two.

but also you can specify full path to the composer (eg. `/usr/local/bin/composer install ...`)

btw, why separate ssh connections? you can do it in one line

```
ssh ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_SERVER} "cd ${DEPLOY_DIR} && git pull origin main && /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader"
```

Comment: Specifying the full path works! And you're right this should be done in one line, it was only for testing reasons separated. Thank you for your help!